# Is there a Hadith with this chain: Imam Ahmad < al Shafi’i < Malik Ibn Anas < Nafi’ < Ibn Umar < The Prophet?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

We know that

> Imam Malik Ibn Anas < Nafi < Ibn Umar < The Prophet

Is famously praised as the “golden chain”, and Im also aware Imam al Shafi'i studied under Imam Malik for a while, and Imam Ahmad studied under Imam al Shafi’i

So I was just wondering if Imam Ahmad wrote a Hadith with the chain:

> < al Shafi’i < Malik < Nafi < Ibn Umar < the Prophet

as seeing the golden chain extended with three of the four imams is just extremely appealing to me.

I don’t remember ever reading it in the Musnad Ahmad although I could have missed it, and i did not find anything using word searches.

Is there any Hadith with this chain?

Comment: The golden chain is a chain al-Bukhari preferred, but other scholars have different views and also regarded there preference as the most authentic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following hadith in the Musnad of Imam Ahmad has that chain:

> حَدَّثَنا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ إدْرِيسَ الشّافِعِيُّ، أخْبَرَنا مالِكٌ، عَنْ نافِعٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ، أنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ﷺ قالَ: «لا يَبِعْ بَعْضُكُمْ عَلى بَيْعِ بَعْضٍ»
>
> Muhammad ibn Idris Ash-Shafi'i narrated to us: Malik reported to us from Nafi from Ibn Umar that the Prophet (SAW) said: One of you shouldn't buy over the buying of another.
>
> ([Musnad Ahmad 5862](https://app.turath.io/book/13157?page=5729))

It is also reported in Bukhari and Muslim through Malik, and it is recorded in Malik's Muwatta.

Comment: Oh wow. jazakallah. This chain really is a work of art. Does this chain exist in another hadith, but with less connections of the form: عن ?

Comment: What an overpowered chain. Although technically not as reliable as the golden chain, it matches it in beauty :)

Comment: @Maalik since imam a Shafi'i  died rather young many narration he could have reported would be taken by hadith scholars from other sources since it is highly appreciated to have a high sanad meaning a minimum amount of narrators between the final reporter and the prophet (). Imam Muslim for example who came later than Ahmad reported it via a chain of the same length from the student of Malik Yahya ibn Yahya (ibn Kathir or ibn Bukayr) [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1412e) he also reported longer versions of the same hadith via al-Laith ibn Sa'ad from his students with the same length.

Comment: Malik himself reported a version of the hadith via abu az-Zinad from al-'Araj from abu Hurairah, which Muslim also compiled. While al-Bukhari reported it via 'Abdullah ibn Yusuf a student of Malik see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2165). To come back to a shafi'i neither Muslim nor al-Bukhari would have reported it via the chain of Ahmad and compiled it in their sahih for the simple reason that it has a lower sanad. However if they saw a necessity of citing it they would quote it after such a narration with a high sanad just as a backup.